# neo4j cant be installed

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

I have tried following the official guide provided by neo4j for installation in Ubuntu,but at one point I wrongly added 2 entries in the sources.list file and tried installing. After that I removed the entries and started from the beginning but It shows this error.

```
$ sudo apt-get install neo4j
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
neo4j : Depends: daemon but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

rebuild the sources.list file and run sudo apt-get update. In my case the sources.list file was missing and hence had to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

I was also following the instructions on the [neo4j docu](http://debian.neo4j.org/) on a server with **Ubuntu 18.04**.
I ran into the exact same error message posted above, when I was doing

```
sudo apt-get install neo4j
```

Updating my `sources.list` and `gpg keys` solved the problem.

Here you can find how to update them:
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44066273/9994393) contains step-by-step instructions