# neo4j : Depends: daemon but it is not installable

Tags: neo4j

Anybody having this issue on ubuntu 14?

```
>sudo apt-get install neo4j
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 neo4j : Depends: daemon but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I followed the steps here:

https://debian.neo4j.org/

but I cannot get past this error

Comment: May be duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290467/neo4j-cant-be-installed.

Answer (score 3):

The below worked for me,

1. https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/
2. Select the **country/ubuntu** version
3. Select **Main/Universe** from ubuntu branches (box)
4. Select **Security/Updates** from ubuntu updates (box)

*(although you can select the other items if it suits your need)*

5. Goto the bottom of the page and click on **generate list**

***This will take you the new page where it displays all the sources and gpg keys required for you***

6. updates your **/etc/apt/sources.list** file either using the command displayed on the screen or by manually coping it

**Please Note: If you use the command displayed on the page, it will overwrite your sources.list, if you have either backup your sources.list file or manually update the file with contents displayed on the screen**

7. update the gpg keys with the command displayed on the screen

Next, run the below,

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install daemon